# Find a "native" dll which calculates a MD5/SHA1 hash in windows 2003 server

Tags: com, windows-server-2003

Does anyone know if there exist a dll in windows (2003 server) which I can call to calculate a MD5/SHA1 hash for a string?

I've written a .dll in C# that do this but I'm not allowed to use this because of company regulations for our servers.

/Ausgar

Comment: What COM based language do you want to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do have a .NET 2.0 installed (which I think you do), then yes, there is one.

It's accessible via COM as `System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider` and `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1`, respectively.

It's no use to implent it in C# as C# relies on .NET and .NET has implemented it for you already.

P.S. If there is no .NET on your system or you reluct at using .NET/COM for some reason, then there is [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/cryptest.aspx) using [Microsoft Crypto API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380256(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: I think the idea is provided Hashing to COM based consumer.  Whether these providers can be used may depend on the consumer, e.g, VBScript may struggle to use these providers

Comment: What are you saying? That these classes can't be used from VBScript/VB6?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [openSSL](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html)?

(e.g. there are precompiled libeay32.dll and libssl32.dll files for windows, I'm not sure where the docs are that describe the DLL functions available in each of those, though)